# How can I make login page using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could please anyone tell me how to build login page with api
And after logged in go to dashboard where sidebar is dynamic and memus are fetched with api.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Sidebar = () => {

  const [menuData, setMenuData] = useState([]);

  // const API_TOKEN = process.env.REACT_APP_API_TOKEN;

  const fetchMenuData = async () => {

    try {

      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:9292/fndMenu/menuloadbyuser', {

        method: "GET",

        headers: {

          

        },

      });

      if (response.ok) {

        const data = await response.json();

        setMenuData(Array.isArray(data) ? data : [data]);

      } else {

        console.error("Error fetching menu data. Status:", response.status);

      }

    } catch (error) {

      console.error('Error fetching menu data:', error);

    }

  };

  useEffect(() => {

    fetchMenuData();

  }, []);

  const renderSubMenus = (subMenus) => {

    if (!subMenus || subMenus.length === 0) {

      return null;

    }

    return (

      <ul>

        {subMenus.map((submenu) => (

          <li key={submenu.menuItemId}>

            {submenu.menuItemDesc}

            {renderSubMenus(submenu.subMenus)}

          </li>

        ))}

      </ul>

    );

  };

  return (

    <div>

      <h2>Sidebar</h2>

      <ul>

        {menuData.map((menuItem) => (

          <li key={menuItem.menuItemId}>

            {menuItem.menuItemDesc}

            {renderSubMenus(menuItem.subMenus)}

          </li>

        ))}

      </ul>

    </div>

  );

};

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: You've provided no details on what "log in" means nor how your API is authenticated.  No one can help you until you provide *all* of that information in explicit and clear detail.

Comment: I have to make login page where user can enter email and password and I have an api so how to do it . Like login page using api  . When user enter correct email and password they will be directed to dashboard page . And in dashboard menus are dynamic.